# Application doesn't start, gives error "failed to start child: Odt.Endpoint"

Tags: ubuntu, elixir, phoenix-framework

After command "mix phoenix.server" always receive error:

```
=INFO REPORT==== 14-Dec-2015::20:55:48 ===

    application: logger
    exited: stopped
    type: temporary

** (Mix) Could not start application odt: Odt.start(:normal, []) returned an error: shutdown: failed to start child: Odt.Endpoint

** (Exit) shutdown: failed to start child: Phoenix.Endpoint.Server

** (Exit) shutdown: failed to start child: {:ranch_listener_sup, Odt.Endpoint.HTTP}

** (Exit) shutdown: failed to start child: :ranch_acceptors_sup

** (Exit) {:listener_error, Odt.Endpoint.HTTP, :eaddrinuse}
```

How can I fix it? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Just off the top of my head, I'd guess that last line (:eaddrinuse) means that something is using the port you're trying to open for your Phoenix.  See what you get when you do: http://localhost:4000.  If there is something on your 4000 port then you can modify the port in the dev.exs file.

Comment: Thank You!
After port modify all OK :)

Comment: @imonah Consider answering to your own question so that the community can benefit from what you learned :)

Answer (score 7):

Just so others can find the answer should they run into this issue:

This line:

```
** (Exit) {:listener_error, Odt.Endpoint.HTTP, :eaddrinuse}
```

means that something is already using the 4000 port (which is the default port for Phoenix). Try checking this `http://localhost:4000` to see if you see anything.  If you do, then modify the port that Phoenix opens via changing your `dev.exs` file.

Comment: You are guessing right, the error `EADDRINUSE` literally means "The given address is already in use." http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/bind.2.html#ERRORS

Comment: @PatrickOscity LOL--I guess it would have paid for me to just check the docs. :)

Answer (score 3):

I'm using mac, so this answer would be the same for linux

just run `lsof -i :4000` to see which proceses are using that port.

Once you identify the one corresponding to phoenix (beam.smp), just kill the process

`kill -9 PID`

or you can just do `killall beam.smp`

Cheers